# Trigger Form Submission from inside React useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my React component, I need to listen for a value to change then trigger a form to be submitted.

Currently I'm using a `useEffect` hook to listen for changes to a state variable `mediaBlob`,

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Foo({
  handleSubmit,
  ...props
}) {

  let { mediaBlob, setMediaBlob } = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mediaBlob) {
      // how to trigger the form submission here?
      // Cant call the form's handleSubmit() method without an event
    }
  }, [mediaBlob]);
```

but I cant call the form's `handleSubmit` function because the function needs to accept an event object `e`.

```js
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // ...
}


return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Foo handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  </form>
)
```

Is it still possible to trigger the form submission from within the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: how does `mediaBlob` get changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract code after `e.preventDefault()` into another function and call that from `useEffect`. In case you need to get form Data from the event, you also need to use ref to get reference to form element and extract needed data. You can also use controlled inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible to trigger form submission form within `useEffect` using `useRef` here is sample code:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export function Foo({
  handleSubmit,
  ...props
}) {
  const { mediaBlob, setMediaBlob } = useState(null)
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mediaBlob) {
      ref.current.submit();
    }
  }, [mediaBlob]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={ref}>
      {/* form content */}
    </form>
  )
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Foo handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  </form>
)
```